# Determinar sort column en un datagridview c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```
        DataGridViewColumn sortcolum = data.SortedColumn;
        ListSortDirection dir;

        data.DataSource = "";
        /* Cargar datos */
        data.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTable();
        /* Set Grid */

        if (sortcolum != null)
        {
            if (data.SortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                dir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                // Sort a new column and remove the old SortGlyph.
                dir = ListSortDirection.Descending;
            }

            data.Sort(sortcolum, dir);
            sortcolum.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection =
                dir == ListSortDirection.Ascending ?
                SortOrder.Ascending : SortOrder.Descending;
        }
```

Ya puedo determinar por cual columna esta ordenado el DataGridView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al refrescar el objeto, y ordenar por el mismo campo, me genera un error,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  {DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name=campo8, Index=0 }}
```

todo esto, justo despues de refrescar el DV.

La línea que causa el error:

```
data.Sort(sortcolum, dir);
```

El mensaje de error:

> La columna proporcionada no pertence a este control DataGridView.

Comment: Para ver más claro el error pon entera toda la información que tengas para seguir la traza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
data.DataSource = CCarsData.ConexionDB.CargarTable();
```

... esto reconstruye internamente las instancias de `DataGridViewColumn` que forman parte del DGV.  De modo que tu instancia `sortcolum` ya no *pertenece* al DGV y no lo puedes usar *directamente* para hacer el sort.

Lo que sí puedes hacer es usar `sortcolum` para *encontrar* la nueva instancia de `DataGridViewColumn` que sí pertenece al DGV y que comparte el mismo nombre.

Prueba cambiando:

```
data.Sort(sortcolum, dir);
```

... a:

```
data.Sort(data.Columns[sortcolum.Name], dir);
```

Comment: no me funciono del todo, pero me dio pie para la solucion, gracias